# Spring cron expression for run job every quarterly third week of friday

Tags: java, spring

i have job which has scheduled below
(cron = "0 0 19 02 01 ?") every year 02 of jan at 7 pm now i need to run for quarterly of third week of friday of year is there is any way . i am using spring cron scheduler instead of quartz.

Comment: What does "quarterly of third week of friday of year" mean? Does it mean "third friday of quarter", e.g. for 2018 that would be Jan 19, Apr 20, Jul 20, and Oct 19?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "quarterly of third week of friday of year" you mean "third friday of each quarter", then this will do:

`0 0 19 15-21 1,4,7,10 FRI`

It only matches:

- 7 PM (`0 0 19`)
- Fridays (`FRI`)
- 3rd Friday of a month will be dated between 15th and 21st (`15-21`)
- 3rd Friday of each quarter will be in January, April, July, or October (`1,4,7,10`).

*Test*

```
CronSequenceGenerator cronGen = new CronSequenceGenerator("0 0 19 15-21 1,4,7,10 FRI");
java.util.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf("2018-01-01");
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    date = cronGen.next(date);
    System.out.println(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, yyyy 'at' hh:mm:ss a").format(date));
}
```

*Output*

```
Fri, Jan 19, 2018 at 07:00:00 PM
Fri, Apr 20, 2018 at 07:00:00 PM
Fri, Jul 20, 2018 at 07:00:00 PM
Fri, Oct 19, 2018 at 07:00:00 PM
Fri, Jan 18, 2019 at 07:00:00 PM
Fri, Apr 19, 2019 at 07:00:00 PM
Fri, Jul 19, 2019 at 07:00:00 PM
Fri, Oct 18, 2019 at 07:00:00 PM
Fri, Jan 17, 2020 at 07:00:00 PM
Fri, Apr 17, 2020 at 07:00:00 PM
Fri, Jul 17, 2020 at 07:00:00 PM
Fri, Oct 16, 2020 at 07:00:00 PM
```